# thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues

Tags: c++

I'm currently trying to learn to use threads and I have a problem with passing arguments to a function executed in another thread.

```cpp
void Class::foo(const string& a, size_t b, Obj& c);
```

(the thread executing this function is declared inside the class Class)

for the last agument I use std::ref() as mentioned in the documentation but I still face the same compilation error.

When I create a test function in the anonymous namespace with the same prototype, the error does not appear.

Is there a problem with executing a class method in a different thread ? How is it possible to solve the problem ?

here is the error :

```
/usr/include/c++/8/thread:120:17: error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues
  static_assert( __is_invocable<typename decay<_Callable>::type,
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           typename decay<_Args>::type...>::value,
```

and the parameters I use to create the thread :

```cpp
(&Class::foo, cref(charSet), b, ref(c))
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] as well as the actual errors you get, copy-pasted (as text!) in full and complete.

Comment: As a couple of guesses, did you remember to pass a `Class` object as the first argument? Did you remember to use `std::cref` for the `a` argument?

Comment: My psychic powers tell me you forgot to pass `Class*` or `Class&` parameter, referring to the object the member function should be called on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `invoke` on non-static member, you have to pass instance of `Class`, otherwise you will take another overload which won't identify  first argument as invokable.

```
 std::invoke(&Class::foo, instance_of_class, cref(charSet), b, ref(c) );
```

Same situation with `std::thread`, which even is shown in examples of its use:

```
 foo f;
 
 std::thread t5(&foo::bar, &f);
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to pass a Class object as argument... Thank you so much everyone !!

```cpp
(&Class::foo, this, cref(charSet), b, ref(c))
```